# Plugins framework for an Android app

Tags: android, framework

I want to implement a plugin system for [an Open Source app](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/anki-android/VJYB4dxi64E), because it has become really large, with many features that only a few users need. Releasing different apps is not a good solution, because userA wants feature7 and feature24 whilst userB wants feature39 and feature24.

The main parts would be:

- A way for developers to create plugins, including their metadata
- A kind of official repository where approved plugins are made available. This could be a specially-crafted HTTP site, or an FTP server, or Play Store (in which case there is nothing special to do for this part), or anything else.
- A way for users to download/enable/disable plugins, either from the official repository or directly as a file

Is there a sort of library or framework (or at least a collection of code snippets) to ease up the construction of such a system?

Here is what I would like a plugin to be able to do:

- Redefine the layout of a particular screen ([load deflated XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197844/inflate-xml-file-from-internal-memory)?)
- Redefine a method of a class ([load dex class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik)?, [AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759232/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android)?)

For instance, one of the plugins must add a button on a particular screen, and clicking this button increments a value in the app's database. This is not doable with Content Providers and Intents, as far as I know. **In every answer, please describe how the proposed solution would deal with this scenario, thanks!**

I want to avoid making the core app's code complex with hooks for everything.

Solutions must be free, and any resulting code/files should be releasable as open source.